# Get HTML tags and text

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently working on creating a table that allows me to sort rows in ascending and descending order as well as click and drag columns around.  I have that working, but I would like to improve it.  Currently I'm getting the header and cell element text and then concatenating the HTML tags to the string:

`var row = "<td>" + myData + "</td>";`

What I want to know is if jQuery has a method/function that would allow me to get the text with the tags attached to just the one element.

I have tried `.text()` `.html()` `.contents();` `.parent().html()`.  The function `.parent().html()` is the closest to what I want, but it gives me all the rows with tags and text, as opposed to just the one I want.

So what I want to save in my variable is `<th>First Column</th>` not just `First Column`.

Here is a fiddle example of what I've tried and with basic HTML markup and links to the API I researched:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jd6x7/1/)

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
[.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Update:

For those curious why I'm doing this, here is my side project:

[Table Sorter](http://jsfiddle.net/3JRSz/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: Implementing the sorting by concatenating HTML as text doesn't sound like a good idea. It would be better if you just used jQuery methods to move elements around instead.

Comment: I'll check it out, I kept finding nothing but getting a specific element or text.  Thanks, I'll see if it helps.

Comment: Please know the difference between `tag` and `element`

Comment: @Bondye `element` = A pair of `tags` with or without content. `tag` = Well it's a `<tag>`.  What else is there and how does that help?

Comment: @Juhana I added my actual project if you have a better idea of I could do it please let me know.  Doing it that way was the easiest I could find to simple sort an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outerHTML` property.

```
var html = $(this).prop('outerHTML');
```

Or:

```
var html = this.outerHTML;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qy8GS/

Comment: Awesome works like a champ!  I figured there had to be something but I couldn't find it :(  Time limit before I can accept it, you're too fast!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/aCTva/1/

```
$.fn.outerHTML = function () {
    var $t = $(this).eq(0);
    if ("outerHTML" in $t[0]) {
        return $t[0].outerHTML;
    } else {
        return $t.clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
    }
};


alert($(this).outerHTML());
```

Answer (score 0):

New jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EdD7U/2/

```js
$("tr").each(function () {
    var colIndex = 0;

    $(this).find("td").each(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('th')
            .each(function(index) {
                if (index == colIndex) {
                    var colHeader = $(this).prop("outerHTML");
                    alert(colHeader);
                }
            });

        colIndex++;
    });            
});
```

Basically, save the index of the `tr` you're in, and then grab a few parents up the dom (to `table`) and then find the `th` tags. For each `th` tag, only output the `th` of the index from the original `tr`. The variable you're trying to obtain is `colHeader`.